# Using ES6 template string to query sql database

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, sequelize.js

Here's my code. 
First I defined user table

```
'use strict';
const db = require('../db');
const DataTypes = db.Sequelize;

module.exports = db.define('user', {
    firstName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    lastName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    number1: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    number2: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    }
})
```

Here I want to update number1 and number2 by an array which saves all the numbers

```
var arr = [1,2]
User.findAll(req.body)
.then(users => {
    for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        users.update({
            'number'+ (i+1): '2',
        })
    }
})
```

So this give me a syntax error, which means sequelize doesn't recognize this part `'number'+ (i+1)`.

If I use template string like this `number${i+1}`, it still cannot work.

but when I try "number1", it works!
Why? and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an issue with Sequelize, this is an issue with your JavaScript syntax (hence the syntax error).

In order to get a "dynamic" or "computed" key for the object that you pass to `users.update`, you need to use `[]` for [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

```
  users.update({
    [`number${i+1}`]: '2',
  })
```